# SpringIntegration JavaMail Sender IMAP AuthenticationException

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

Here is my xml file to receive messages from email

```
    <int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="customAdapter"
            store-uri="imaps://test520521%40gmail.com:****@imap.gmail.com:993/inbox"
            channel="receiveChannel"
            auto-startup="true"
            should-delete-messages="false"  
            should-mark-messages-as-read="false"
            java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"/>

    <util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
        <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
        <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
        <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
        <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
    </util:properties>
```

But for some reason After executing the above code getting below Exception

Looks like there's an issue with Authentication, but authentication details are correctly provided

```
19:25:02.441 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG o.s.i.mail.ImapMailReceiver - connecting to store [imaps://test520521@gmail.com:*****@imap.gmail.com:993/inbox]
19:25:12.086 [task-scheduler-1] WARN  o.s.i.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter - error occurred in idle task
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:566) ~[mail-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288) ~[mail-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169) ~[mail-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118) ~[mail-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.connectStoreIfNecessary(AbstractMailReceiver.java:228) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openFolder(AbstractMailReceiver.java:235) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:156) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:220) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:190) [spring-integration-mail-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_20]
19:25:12.086 [task-scheduler-1] WARN  o.s.i.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter - Failed to execute IDLE task. Will attempt to resubmit in 10000 milliseconds.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure in 'idle' task. Will resubmit.
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:239) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:190) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:566) ~[mail-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288) ~[mail-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169) ~[mail-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118) ~[mail-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.connectStoreIfNecessary(AbstractMailReceiver.java:228) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openFolder(AbstractMailReceiver.java:235) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:156) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:220) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow google's instructions in the exception? ...

```
Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
```

i.e. do you have 2 step auth enabled?

Comment: Thanks Gary for you reply....I have enabled the IMAP and Pop3 access for my google account, I enabled from my google settings, Is there anything I need to do?

Comment: Read the instructions on their link; you might have to click the link at "Learn how to allow less secure apps access to your account."